# How to know CSV line count before loading in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am new to python and have a requirement to load dataframes from various CSV files. It turns out that there is a business logic depending on the number of rows in csv. Can i know this beforehand if i can know CSV total row numbers without writing read_csv?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, you can:

```
lines = sum(1 for line in open('/path/to/file.csv'))
```

but be aware that Pandas will read the whole file **again**

if you are sure that the whole file will fit into memory we can do this:

```
with open('/path/to/file.csv') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    lines = len(data)
    df = pd.read_csv(data, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although the files have only 1000-4000 lines and i think these can fir in memory. But are there ways to know that also if file fits in or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file without saving the contents. Try:

```
with open(filename, "r") as filehandle:
    number_of_lines = len(filehandle.readlines())
```